# Design noise filter and controller for a system based on reference model

Tags: filter, control

I have a practical system which can be described in the form \$ \frac{k}{s(Ts+1)} = \frac{5}{s(0.03s+1)}\$ (1).

My objective is to design a controller for the system to guarantee that the closed-loop looks like \$ G = \frac{1}{T_ps+1} = \frac{1}{0.035s+1}\$ (2) the most. I see that the bandwidth of (2) is about 30Hz. The bandwidth of reference signal is 20Hz.

Therefore, I have implemented a PD controller for this and it partially meets the requirements. However, the sensor results in a lot of random noise, which makes the output slightly oscillatory. So, how to design an reasonable filter to guarantee both noise rejection and bandwidth for (2)? How can I improve the controller?

Comment: Please disclose your PD controller. It would also help if you diagram out how you approached its development, as well. Your results should also be added, showing the "slightly oscillatory" behavior. When you ask "how can I improve X?" it's probably a good idea to disclose X. (I mean, sure, most of us bought one of those crystal balls at some point in our lives. But I don't think any of us actually got one that worked. I sure didn't.)

Comment: Your system has an integral term (1/s) and, to get rid of that you need a differential term in the numerator. That will create noise.

Comment: You could cancel the pole at \$s=-\frac{1}{0.03}\$ and add a gain term to tune the closed loop time constant. But that would still introduce a differentiator and produce a potential dipole if the pole and zero are not exactly equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "*closed loop looks like G **the most***" ? What does **the most** mean here ?